# converting html to pdf using itext the image result in pdf is small unlike the original

Tags: itext

As a beginner in android, I was having a hard time converting html to pdf, every time I convert the html to pdf the result image inside the pdf file is small. How can I solve this problem? This code I am using to convert the html:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
document.open();
InputStream htmlPath = getAssets().open(filename + ".html");
XMLWorkerHelper helper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
helper.parseXHtml(writer, document, htmlPath);
document.close();
writer.close();
```

this is the result:

[image: this is the result]

Comment: The image may be too small in your opinion, but it might be the right size in someone else's opinion. Without more info, I fail to see how someone can help you: what is the size of the original image? Did you define a size in the `<img>` tag? If you defined a size, did you define it in `px` or using another measurement unit? Is the image part of a table (maybe the cell causes the image to scale down)? Do you understand why your question can't be answered? Your question isn't clear at all; it currently sounds like a subjective question: *"I feel that the image is too small."*

Comment: Sorry for my unspecified question.I define the size inside <img> tag using percentage,there is no table used and the original size of the picture is 740x357.Thank you for your fast response.

Comment: What is the size of the image in the PDF? It should be 10.28 x 4.95 inch (or 26.1 x 12.6 cm). Why don't you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with a simple HTML and the resulting PDF that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Indeed, without a reproducible example this is pure guesswork. That been said, you use the iText 5.x `XMLWorker` while the newer, improved iText HTML rendering module is based on iText 7.